# Getting apihelper module from Dive into Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with chapter 4 of this book. I run python shell (IDLE, python 2.7) and try to import apihelper module, but I keep getting traceback saying

```
No module named apihelper
```

I downloaded the code from Pilgrim's site, but it still doesn't work. What do I miss?

Comment: You should post the code you tried instead?...

Comment: What do you mean? I typed "from apihelper import info" like in the book and later tried only "import apihelper" but I keep getting same traceback. Is this what you asked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your Python interpreter doesn't know where did you download `apihelper` module, and it cannot import it.

More about where does `import` look for packages you can **[read here](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html#d0e4550)** in Dive into Python book.

Comment: So as far as I understand I have to append apihelper? But what should I type as "my new path"? `sys.path.append('/Home/Desktop/apihelper.py')` ? If so, then I'm still doing something wrong. (The apihelper file is on my desktop ofc)

Comment: As I see, you use some *NIX based system. Did you try to run Python on '/Home/Desktop/' path? apihelper.py should be accessible from there.